# Insert an image/company logo from ax to excel

Tags: excel, dynamics-ax-2009, axapta

How to insert an image/company logo from ax to excel?

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this](http://dynamicsuser.net/forums/t/16803.aspx). I think it might be helpful.